# invalid hook call with nextjs inside custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting a invalid hook call error when using state inside my custom hook. Here's my code

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useFetch() {
  const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState<number>();
  setRandomValue(3);

  return randomValue;
}
```

the hook is inside my hooks folder on the path: ./src/hooks

any reason for that?

Comment: Why are you call setRandomvalue just after useState. If you want you can use like 


`const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState<number>(3);`


What are trying to achieve here??

Comment: this is supposed to be a custom hook, the fixed number is being used as an example, the problem is that the useState was supposed to work inside custom hooks that carries the "use" prefix

Comment: @VoQuocThang `useFetch` is obviously a custom React hook, but besides that, React hooks ***are only validly*** called from within React functions or custom hooks.

Comment: Yeah, useFetch is supposed to be a custom hook to fetch my api, the logic inside it is a just a example that I tried when debugging. This hook is being called in a react list component, and the code works just fine if left it inside that component. The real problem is when I try to create a custom hook to avoid repeating code

Comment: How do you call `useFetch()`?

Comment: I ask because custom hooks must obey the Rules of hooks as well https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: the file name is useFetch.ts, I called it inside my component, productList.tsx,  inside a useEffect, with pages as a dependency , so when pages change the useFetch is called again

Comment: @AlexWayne in that case, I can't call useFetch inside a useEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment mentions you call `useFetch()` from inside `useEffect()`. That's where your problem is.

Hooks are only valid when called during render of a component. `useEffect()` is triggered after a render. So you cannot call any hook from inside `useEffect`.

It's hard to advise how to fix that since you haven't posted that code.

---

Also, and this is equally important, *never* call a state setter function during render. And remember that hook functions run when the component renders. Setting state triggers a render, so this typically results in an infinite loop.

Most of time when fetching a value and setting it in state, you should have a valid initial value for its type (like `null`), and a `useEffect()` to set something you want.

Remember that `useEffect` means "use side effect" where a side effect is something that a render may trigger, but is not executed synchronously every single render.

```
export default function useFetch() {
  const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState<number | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRandomValue(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }, [setRandomValue]}


  return randomValue;
}
```

---

Comment: Well, it is simply because it's ***not*** being called by the `useEffect` hook, but rather the callback that is passed to the `useEffect` hook. This fails the rules of hooks because you can't call hooks in callbacks or conditionally.